# transfer files from sftp server to another sftp server with mule flow

Tags: mule, sftp

```
<flow name="test1" doc:name="test1">
    <sftp:inbound-endpoint host="${source.server.host}"
        port="${source.server.port}" path="${source.server.customer.path}" user="${source.server.user}"
        password="${source.server.password}" responseTimeout="10000"
        pollingFrequency="${source.server.pollfrequency}" doc:name="source SFTP server" connector-ref="SFTPone"/>
    <sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
        outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]"
        host="${target.server.host}" port="${target.server.port}" path="${target.server.customer.path}"
        user="${target.server.user}" password="${target.server.password}"
        responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Intermediate Host" connector-ref="TARGETSFTPone"/>
</flow>
<flow name="test2" doc:name="test2">
    <sftp:inbound-endpoint host="${source.server.host}"
        port="${source.server.port}" path="${source.server.wells.path}" user="${source.server.user}"
        password="${source.server.password}" responseTimeout="10000"
        pollingFrequency="${source.server.pollfrequency}" doc:name="source SFTP server" connector-ref="SFTPtwo"/>
    <sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
        outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]"
        host="${target.server.host}" port="${target.server.port}" path="${target.server.wells.path}"
        user="${target.server.user}" password="${target.server.password}"
        responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Intermediate Host" connector-ref="TARGETSFTPtwo"/>
</flow>
```

I want to transfer files from sftp server with multiple path,I had configure ten flows like this in one project,they will access the diffent path on one SFTP server to tranfer files to another SFTP server's diffent path at the same time. But when I ran this project, it returned "SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Too many users for this IP" , How can I resolve this issue, or there are better ways to meet this requirement.
any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of foreach + dynamic endpoints but the drawback is that you would need to disable streaming in your SFTP connector (or use an object-to-stream-transformer) just after your inbound endpoint i.e: it would look like

```
<sftp:inbound endpoint>
<object-to-byte-array />
<set-variable variableName="fileContents" value="#[payload]" />
<foreach value="#[expressionToTheListOfSites]">
    <set-variable variableName="site" value="#[payload]" />
    <set-payload value="#[fileContents]" />
    <sftp:outbound-endpoint address="sftp://#[site]" />
</foreach>
```

You may need to fix the syntax but the logic would be that one.

Comment: thank you for you answer,Juan.
According to your flow configuration,
The flow can perform transfer files on sftpA's PATH(A) to sftpB's PATH(A),PATH(B),PATH(C).....Is that correct?  But my requirement is something like this: transfer files on sftpA's PATH(A) to sftpB's PATH(A), transfer files on sftpA's PATH(B) to sftpB's PATH(B),transfer files on sftpA's PATH(C) to sftpB's PATH(C)...at the same time.   any suggestion??   Great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Inbound:

EndpointBuilder endpointBuilder = eventContext
                .getMuleContext()
                .getEndpointFactory()
                .getEndpointBuilder(
                        "sftp"+"://" + userName+ ":"
                                + password+ "@"
                                + host+ ":"+port
                                + path+"?connector=SFTPIN");

 InboundEndpoint inboundEndPoint = endpointBuilder.buildInboundEndpoint();

    endpointBuilder.addMessageProcessor(new MessageFilter(new WildcardFilter("sample*")));

    endpointBuilder.setExchangePattern(MessageExchangePattern.REQUEST_RESPONSE);

    MuleMessage message= inboundEndPoint.request(1000000L);

outbound:

//To send file to destination 
    EndpointBuilder outboundEndpointBuilder = eventContext
            .getMuleContext()
            .getEndpointFactory()
            .getEndpointBuilder(
                    "sftp"+"://" + userName+ ":"
                            + password+ "@"
                            + host+ ":"+port
                            + path+"?connector=SFTPOUT");

    OutboundEndpoint outboundPoint=outboundEndpointBuilder.buildOutboundEndpoint();

    SftpConnector sftpConnector=(SftpConnector) outboundPoint.getConnector();

    sftpConnector.setOutputPattern("sample1.txt");
    eventContext.getMuleContext().getClient().process(outboundPoint, msg);
```

Comment: you can chage th e username and host name as required and invoke explicity.